# How to correctly use whereNotNull() in Laravel's collections? (Not working as I'd thought)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm writing this app to do some office pool on the NFL games, so I have a table where I store the game results, it basically has date and time of the game, visitor and local, and scores. Now I want to write a model attribute to get the team's record (W-L-D), so first I have to get how many games the team has played, I'm trying this:

```
$games = Game::whereNotNull('homescore')
  ->whereNotNull('awayscore')
  ->where('home','PIT')
  ->orWhere('away','PIT')
  ->get()
```

So this should give me all the games played by PIT as away or home, and only the games where a score is present, right?

Well... it's not working. If I take away both `->wherNotNUll()` I correctly get the 17 games PIT will play in a season. But if I use them it gets me 10 games. Not at random, it alway get me the same 10 games. In all those games PIT is involved, at least.

This is one of the records I'm getting:

```
  App\Models\Juego {#4788
    id: 4010,
    season: 2022,
    week: 4,
    valid: "2022-10-02 12:00:00",
    away: "NYJ",
    awayscore: null,
    home: "PIT",
    homescore: null,
    dif: null,
    created_at: "2023-02-05 22:24:09",
    updated_at: "2023-02-06 13:18:26",
  },
```

I even break up the query doing something like:

```
$games = Game::where('home','PIT')->orWhere('away','PIT')
```

(This gives 17 correct results) and then over that result applying the `$games->whereNotNull('homescore')` and `awayscore` and still gives me the 10 results (the query should be giving me 4 results, where there are final score for the game)

Answer (score 4):

its become a mess because of the combination of `whereNotNull`, `where` and `orWhere`

the `orWhere` messes up your whole sql query logic and does not work the way you expect.

Just put the `where/orWhere` in a closure and it should be fine

```
Game::whereNotNull('homescore')
    ->whereNotNull('awayscore')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('home', 'PIT')
        ->orWhere('away', 'PIT');
    })
    ->get();
```

just a bit of explanation,

this is the raw sql of your query, everything is fine until the `OR` is added

```
WHERE homescore IS not NULL 
AND awayscore IS not NULL 
AND home = 'PIT' 
OR away = 'PIT'
```

with closure it becomes like this (which is probably what you are wanting)

```
WHERE homescore IS not NULL 
AND awayscore IS not NULL 
AND (home = 'PIT' or away = 'PIT')
```